# Script Skipping Over Element that Exists - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a script that loops through multiple pages.  It works for the most part, but I have been getting an error that `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` for the link even though the element exists.  I added an if, else statement that allows the script to run but it leaves me with a blank field for a link on a record or two that should be there.  Here is my working script with the if, else statement.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work without the if, else statement?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

base_url = "https://www.doabooks.org/"

books = []
n = 5
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (i == 1):
        # handle first page
        response = urlopen(base_url)
    response = urlopen(base_url + "doab?func=browse&page=" + str(i) + "&queryField=A&uiLanguage=en")
    page_html = response.read()
    response.close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    #grabs info for each textbook
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"data"})

    for container in containers:
       item = {}
       item['type'] = "Open Access Book"
       item['title'] = container.span.text.strip()
       item['author'] = container.a.text
       if container.find('a', {'itemprop' : 'url'}):
          item['link'] = "https://www.doabooks.org" + container.find('a', {'itemprop' : 'url'})['href']
       else:
          item['link'] = ''
       item['source'] = "Directory of Open Access Books"
       if container.find("a",{"itemprop":"about"}):
          item['subject'] = container.find("a",{"itemprop":"about"}).text
       else:
          item['subject'] = ''
       item['base_url'] = "https://www.doabooks.org/"
       books.append(item) # add the item to the list

   with open("./json/doab-test.json", "w") as writeJSON:
       json.dump(books, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: can u specify where is the error occuring ,I mean that specific url and what element you are tying to find?

Comment: it is occurring for the `item['link']` before I did the if,else statement.  The specific url is was running into issues with is https://www.doabooks.org/doab?func=fulltext&uiLanguage=en&rid=13329.  This is link is on the second page and returns "" even though it exists.

Comment: i tried clicking it but is downloading a pdf

Comment: Here is the link to the page https://www.doabooks.org/doab?func=browse&page=2&queryField=A&uiLanguage=en.  The title is 'Aan het buitenland gehecht' I am trying to pull the url from the 'Free Access' link but it keeps coming up blank in my json fle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be a parser issue(i am not sure).However I was able to achieve the data from url by

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
x=requests.get("https://www.doabooks.org/doab?func=browse&page=2&queryField=A&uiLanguage=en")
print(soup(x.content).find_all("div",{"class":"data"})[5].find_all("a",{"itemprop":"url"}))
```

## EDIT

I noticed removing "html.parser" as argument worked perfectly fine for your script.i.e just dont pass second argument while declaring page soup

Comment: Thanks!  It was a parser issue.  I installed and used `html5lib` and it works perfectly.